# Escape dots and asterisks in command line variable output string

Tags: bash, escape-characters

I have a command that sets an environment variable from a command like this:

```
BLACKLIST=$(python tools.py gen-blacklist)
```

Which results in a string that contains dots `*` and asterisks `*`, like this:

```
LISTEN,UNLISTEN,NOTIFY,SHOW,REFRESH,pg_notify,.*remove,.*delete,.*update,.*create,.*insert
```

I want to be able to escape all the dots and asterisks in the string, this is what I have tried:

```
TEMP=$(python tools.py gen-blacklist) && BLACKLIST=$(echo ${TEMP/.\*/\\.\\*}) && echo $BLACKLIST
```

but it only replaces at the first occurence.

```
LISTEN,UNLISTEN,NOTIFY,SHOW,REFRESH,pg_notify,\.\*remove,.*delete,.*update,.*create,.*insert
```

How do I escape for all occurences of `*` and `.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smells like an xy problem, but regardless...

From [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), this is what the manual has to say on `${parameter/pattern/string}`-style expansions -

> If pattern begins with ‘/’, all matches of pattern are replaced with
>   string. Normally only the first match is replaced

Therefore `${TEMP/.\*/\\.\\*}` needs to change to `${TEMP//.\*/\\.\\*}` (notice the additional `/` immediately after `TEMP`).

This yields
`LISTEN,UNLISTEN,NOTIFY,SHOW,REFRESH,pg_notify,\.\*remove,\.\*delete,\.\*update,\.\*create,\.\*insert`

Comment: Holy, so deep in the docs.. and just missing 1 character, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Quote more  (™) ....

Try:

```
TEMP=$(python tools.py gen-blacklist) &&
echo "$TEMP"
```

If you really need the dots and asterisks escaped, use (in bash):

```
TEMP=$(python tools.py gen-blacklist) &&
BLACKLIST=${TEMP//\.\*/\\.\\*} &&
echo "$BLACKLIST"
```